# JPA property access isMethod

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.1

JPA property access: getter and setter. Does it support isMethod for boolean? For example,

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)   
public class Foo {
   private boolean closed;


   public boolean isClosed() {
       return this.closed;
   }

}
```

Could not find relevant info in JPA spec 2.1.

Comment: Yes. It supports. Find in the spec. section 2.3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** It does.

From [`JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence API, Version 2.1`](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

> **2.2 Persistent Fields and Properties**
>
> ...for every persistent property *property* of type *T* of the entity,
>   there is a getter method, *getProperty*, and setter method
>   *setProperty*. For boolean properties, *isProperty* may be used as an alternative name for the getter method.